# Как отключить в unbound запросы с неполными доменами?

Tags: linux, debian

Когда делается dns запрос, в логе unbound видно, что совершаются лишние запросы:

Вот тут делался запрос домена `sas123.google.com`:

```
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: no signer, using sas123.google.com. TYPE0 CLASS0
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: 127.0.0.1 sas123.google.com.example.local. A IN
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: validator operate: query sas123.google.com.example.local. A IN
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: resolving sas123.google.com.example.local. A IN
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: processQueryTargets: sas123.google.com.example.local. A IN
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: sending query: sas123.google.com.example.local. A IN
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: 0RDd mod1 rep sas123.google.com.example.local. A IN
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: iterator operate: query sas123.google.com.example.local. A IN
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: response for sas123.google.com.example.local. A IN
sas123.google.com.example.local.       IN      A
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: finishing processing for sas123.google.com.example.local. A IN
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: validator operate: query sas123.google.com.example.local. A IN
[1605857419] unbound[17690:0] info: no signer, using sas123.google.com.example.local. TYPE0 CLASS0
```

Но unbound сделал лишний запрос `sas123.google.com.example.local`, как это выключить?

Мой `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 213.133.98.98
nameserver 213.133.99.99
options timeout:3 attempts:3 use-vc
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что проблема не в unbound, а в самом хосте, который использует этот резолвер. 1) Покажите `/etc/resolv.conf` на хосте, с которого идут запросы 2) проверьте, если обращаться к DNS напрямую, через диг это выглядит так: `dig sas123.google.com @IP-адрес-unbound` - запросы на .example.local также идут? Думаю, у вас search domain подкидывает проблем

Comment: @TotalPusher /etc/resolv.conf добавил в вопрос. Я и так тестил напрямую запросы, правда не через dig, а через nslookup, там проблема есть да. Честно говоря, я уже успел сменить unbound на dnsmasq, в dnsmasq есть специальная опция в конфиге `domain-needed`, которая это отключает и она работает.